# joining tables with condition fails

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, lambda, entity-framework-core

I am trying to join two list with a condition

```
              var trainerList = await _context.WorkShopTrainers
                .Include(p => p.Trainer)
                .Where(p => p.WorkShopId == request.WorkshopId)
                .Select(p=>new UsersFullNameDto
                {
                    Id = p.TrainerId,
                    FullName= p.Trainer.FullName,
                })
                .ToListAsync();

            var query = await _context.TrainerTimeTables
                .Where(p=>p.MiladiDate==request.TimeTable )                    
                .Join(trainerList, ttt=>ttt.TrainerId, tList => tList.Id ,(ttt,tList)=> new TrainerTimeTableForReserveDto
                {
                    TrainerId = ttt.TrainerId,
                    TrainerName = tList.FullName,
                    GeorgianDate = ttt.MiladiDate,
                    Times = ttt.Times,
                }).ToListAsync();
```

but it fails and gives me this error

> "The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .Where(p => p.MiladiDate == __request_TimeTable_0)\r\n    .Join(\r\n        inner: __p_1, \r\n        outerKeySelector: ttt => ttt.TrainerId, \r\n        innerKeySelector: tList => tList.Id, \r\n        resultSelector: (ttt, tList) => new TrainerTimeTableForReserveDto{ \r\n            TrainerId = ttt.TrainerId, \r\n            TrainerName = tList.FullName, \r\n            GeorgianDate = ttt.MiladiDate, \r\n            Times = ttt.Times \r\n        }\r\n    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

Answer (score 0):

EF is telling you, that you want to write a linq query that EF tries to translate to sql.
But fails.
The reason is that your trainerlist is a separate query and the result already queried when entering the join.
So a pure sql join is not possible anymore.
What you have to do: either rewrite it so the whole thing can be done in a single sql query or (as mentioned in the error message) use `.AsEnumerable` before the join to tell EF that you are done with SQL and it can continue the linq query evaluation in code.

PS: This error is not a lack of functionality but a hint for you what can be done in sql and what has to be done in code.